# How should I interpret this USB packet in a human readable way?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, c

Using a wixel (wireless transmitter/receiver with USB capability, "this "wixel" thingy is a general-purpose microcontroller board that includes, among other things, USB, 2 UART's, and a 2.4GHz radio.") in conjunction with this [wixel app](https://github.com/StephenBlackWasAlreadyTaken/wixel-xDrip/blob/master/apps/dexdrip/dexdrip.c) to read in a transmission from a Dexcom glucose sensor/transmitter, for use in some software I'm writing. Here's the relevant pieces of C code:

```
void print_packet(Dexcom_packet* pPkt) {
    uartEnable();
    printf("%lu %hhu %d\n", dex_num_decoder(pPkt->raw), pPkt->battery, adcConvertToMillivolts(adcRead(0)));
    uartDisable();
}

uint32 dex_num_decoder(uint16 usShortFloat) {
    uint16 XDATA usReversed = usShortFloat;
    uint8 XDATA usExponent = 0;
    uint32 XDATA usMantissa = 0;
    bit_reverse_bytes((uint8*)&usReversed, 2);
    usExponent = ((usReversed & 0xE000) >> 13);
    usMantissa = (usReversed & 0x1FFF);
    return usMantissa << usExponent;
}

void bit_reverse_bytes(uint8* buf, uint8 nLen) {
    uint8 XDATA i = 0;
    for(; i < nLen; i++) {
        buf[i] = bit_reverse_byte(buf[i]);
    }
}

uint8 bit_reverse_byte(uint8 in) {
uint8 XDATA bRet = 0;
if(in & 0x01)
    bRet |= 0x80;
if(in & 0x02)
    bRet |= 0x40;
if(in & 0x04)
    bRet |= 0x20;
if(in & 0x08)
    bRet |= 0x10;
if(in & 0x10)
    bRet |= 0x08;
if(in & 0x20)
    bRet |= 0x04;
if(in & 0x40)
    bRet |= 0x02;
if(in & 0x80)
    bRet |= 0x01;
return bRet;
}
```

My problem is that the readings I get are nonsensical. I'm using Labview to write up my software, so I employ a simple VISA read (listening for a packet) for an unknown number of bytes and a termination character \n. The rest of the Wixel app shows that it's using RTS/CTS hardware flow control, so I've set that up. My problem is that I'm expecting a long decimal (%lu), an unsigned short char (%hhu), and a decimal (%d), but when I read off the individual bytes received as these data types, my values come out weird.

For example, a reading of 98 on the real glucose meter was "117888 215 0\n" in my packet. I've ruled out endianness, as reading the backwards bytes as ASCII gives super strange unicode style characters. I just fail to see how the first number is in any way related to the second one. I honestly think I may just be interpreting the data type incorrectly, although I know that printf gives purely ASCII characters. The last weird thing is that the 215 almost always shows up somewhere in the packet, be it the first number, middle number, or last number. It's quite strange and leads me to believe I might be missing something.

Any help in interpreting this data would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you've defined the format well enough.  It sounds like you're looking for an ASCII string, but USB stuff is typically binary with a not-necessarily-trivial arrangement of bits to try and compress out any unused bits.

Comment: Oh wait, there's a UART in here?  Is this actually a USB->UART converter that then connects to the sensor?  Then I can understand using ASCII, but it adds another point to verify.

Comment: @AaronD I do believe there's a UART in there. Does that make this easier?

Comment: Your code mentions one.  At this point, it's still uncertain whether it's a physical pair of TX/RX lines that can be probed with a logic analyzer, or a virtual construct that's used to save a developer's time somewhere.  It'd be really nice to see what's happening on the raw UART if possible.

Comment: I think you're not so much looking at a USB packet, but rather the payload. You can safely forget it is transmitted over USB as it could equally well be BT or RS-232.

Comment: What are the actual raw bytes you're receiving in your packet (before you push them through your decoder function)?

Comment: Okay, a bit of googling reveals that this mysterious "wixel" thingy is a general-purpose microcontroller board that includes, among other things, USB, 2 UART's, and a 2.4GHz radio.  This should probably be edited into the question.

Comment: @brhans they're the binary representation of the ASCII, x48 x55 x55 x55 x56 etc

Comment: @AaronD edited main body of post to be more helpful w this info.

Comment: @jippie, sorry for the confusion! I'm not well versed in serial comm's jargon

Comment: I suspect that doing uartenable() immediately before printf(), then uartdisable() immediately after may cause problems - the data packet will only be partially received when the decoder function tries to decode it. (but you don't show the uart receive process, so who knows??)

Comment: @PeterBennett Unfortunately, the receiving end is a piece of software running on top of Labview, a graphical programming language that abstracts out all the nitty gritty details of serial comms into what's known as a "VISA Read". More info here if you're curious: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvinstio/visa_read/

What would be a good piece of software to use that would show the bits being received?

Comment: Why do you do your uartEnable() and uartDisable() inside your print_packet function? You've already passed your Dexcom_packet* pPkt pointer to the function before you've enabled your uart. It looks like you're operating on data which was already present there (random? who knows?)

Comment: @brhans, I'm actually not the person who developed this code. I was working on some of my own when I found this, and it seems to work very well. On the receiving end, I always get the full packet, it's just not in a format that I can relate to the actual data I'm collecting. What do you mean by your "already present there" comment?

Comment: Can you show an untouched string of data? I've had some experience with converting Bluetooth medical data transmissions into meaningful data, and sometimes it can get very wonky. So, please show a full data transmission not converted into anything.

Comment: Here it is: `0011000100110001001101110011100000111000 0011100000110010001100010011010100110000` . It should have "98 battery1 battery2" in there somewhere.

Comment: Well - you're passing a pointer to a structure. And I'm assuming that pointer is already pointing to *something*. So  does that *something* already have some valid packet data? Or does it point to a buffer which enableUart() then fills? Seems like really weird program flow to me ...

Comment: Ah I see. So yes, the something does have valid data, but it's encoded somewhat. I think it comes from the sensor as a 16bit float, and gets converted to a uint32 (strange, I know, but again, not my code) by dex_num_decoder. The radio on the wixel listens for the transmitter, and fills dexcom_packet.raw with that "something" which then gets converted for transmission. The whole program is only 500 lines and is linked in the OP under "wixel app" if you want to read into it a bit more.

Comment: Now I"m even more confused. In the Dexcom_packet structure, there's no indication that there should be anything resembling ASCII anywhere in the packet. Its all supposed to be 'raw' binary ints of various sizes (maybe actually formatted as short floats or whatever). If you're seeing ASCII then its not a "Dexcom_packet".

Comment: Printf is what makes them ascii

Comment: Anyone have any ideas yet?

Comment: We've asked for your original untouched data, but all you've shown in return is ASCII. There's really nowhere else to go until you can show us what's actually in the raw packet - not what it looks like after its been "decoded" and ascii'fied.

Comment: Printf converts it's arguments to be in an ASCII format. If you like, I can remove the printf and replace it with something, but anything that I receive over UART will be in an ASCII format. I don't know how else to receive it. I can try and get you pPkt->raw on its own, or even the whole Dexcom_packet, but it's going to be in ASCII, short of there being some other format to transmit it via the UART.

Comment: @AaronD would I need an oscilloscope to measure the UART pins?

Comment: @brhans I have some data! unobfuscated: 36298 141920 215 0

the first is pPkt->raw, then dex_num_decoder(pPkt->raw) then transmitter battery then wixel battery. I used %hu for pPkt->raw. The reading should be 89.

Comment: @ijustlovemath: A 'scope is probably not the right tool here unless you have a really fancy one.  What you need here is a logic analyzer.  Any decent one should decode the data for you in ASCII or at least hexadecimal format.

Comment: Another one: real reading 86, ppkt->raw 19848, dex_num_ppkt->raw 148000

Comment: The values I was getting turn out to be uncalibrated  sensor values that are used in a linear regression. Thanks again for your help in resolving this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the raw value (which is what I was posting about) needs to be calibrated via a linear regression in order to convert it into the value I'm looking for. The inital regression is about `glucose(raw)=1.0*(raw/1000) - 30`, with additional sensor readings being used in a least squares fit to refine the coefficients. When in doubt, do some statistics! Thanks everyone who put forth the effort to help me out!